# Are these Lucky Charms?

Tags: a-dark-room

In "A Dark Room" I noticed I can take a Charm when exploring.  I never seem to run out of them so I take one every time.  I have no idea what they do though.  Are they Lucky Charms?  Do they increase some kind of stat?  Do they make you get attacked more?  Less?

Comment: Their only purpose is being magically delicious.

Comment: @SaintWacko dammit you beat me to it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have one when you're exploring, and you come across a frog in a swamp (`M`), and you give one to it, you will obtain the "gastronome" perk. This will double the amount of health that you gain when you eat cured meat. The perk is permanent, just like all other perks.

Comment: Is this a permanent change or just for that adventure?

Comment: There is also the place where you speak to the old man in a hut.

Comment: `you come across some creature (a frog I think) in a swamp, and you give one to it` it will give you a chocolate bar.

Answer (score 6):

First off, it's an old man in a swamp that you have to give it to, and secondly, the perk is permanent. So every adventure you go on after that, you will heal more from eating meat.